# How to use mapbox-gl-csp.js file with npm?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am trying to use the mapbox csp feature. The [documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/overview/#csp-directives) shows there's a CDN bundle for the CSP distribution. I'm wondering how I could use the CSP distribution with npm. From the node_module, it looks like mapbox-gl-csp.js is included in the mapbox module. 
[mapbox module dist folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGeCO.png)

However, I'm having a hard time understanding how I can switch to the csp distribution rather than the regular mapbox-gl.js in npm. I've tried to add a path in my tsconfig.json, but it doesn't seem to be working and still using the regular mapbox-gl.js:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
        "mapbox-gl": ["./node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl-csp.js"]
    }
}
```

I'm wondering what I should do to make my project use the mapbox csp bundle with npm?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like:

`import MapboxGl from 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl-csp;`

Comment: Thanks, that works! What I am trying to do is to have two distribution, one using the regular mapbox-gl, and one using the csp version. Is there any way that I can decide which mapbox bundle to use at build time instead of changing every mapbox gl import statement? I tried to change that in tsconfig.json's compileroption but still doesn't seem to work

Comment: I thought there was a flag to do something like that in package.json (I used it once to specify to use the dev version of mapbox-gl-js instead of the main one) but I can't seem to find it now.